# problem in calling function

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView that has a UIScrollView as a subview, which in turn has a UIImageView as its subview . I am able to zoom also. But I want to call another function on double tap. Im using this code:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view 
{
     if(view == scrollView)
     {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if([touch tapCount]== 2)
        {
           [self setViewForProductDispaly];
           return YES;
        }

      }
 return NO;

}
```

The above method is not getting called when i tap it.What might be the reson for this.

**my scrollview**

```
scrollView.hidden=NO;
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,self.bounds.size.width,self.bounds.size.height )];

scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
scrollView.delegate =self;
scrollView.bouncesZoom = YES;
scrollView.delaysContentTouches=NO;


bigImageView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
bigImageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
bigImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, bigImg.size.width, bigImg.size.height)];
bigImageView.image = bigImg;
bigImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[scrollView addSubview:bigImageView];
[bigImageView release];

[self addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use UIGestureRecogizers for basic gestures like double tap:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

doubleTapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGestureRecognizer];
```

and in your `handleDoubleTap:` function you can call whatever method you want.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like bigImageView is stretching to fit scrollView when it's added to it. SO, your method is not getting called because you are really tapping on bigImageView, not scrollView.

Comment: That would be my first guess too. You can simply verify this by putting NSLog statements throughout your code to see what is getting executed. try : if(view == bigImageView)